# yo ember tutorial: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: firebase, ember.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing the YoEmber tutorial: https://github.com/zoltan-nz/library-app. Getting the following error- 
`Uncaught Error: permission_denied at /authors: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

I create a Firebase database, as the tutorial requires, with the following rules: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}`

Still, the database is not getting authenticated. I also copied the correct apiKey, authDomain, databaseURL, projectId, storageBucket, and messagingSenderId from firebase.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: http://yoember.com/#setup-a-server-on-firebase <-- did you fill in your credentials?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I didn't update my credentials in Firebase itself, I only updated them in my environment.js file